# javascript - Assign all local scope variables to another object

Tags: javascript, debugging, scope, v8

Is it possible to create a listener which gets called everytime a variable is defined in a local scope? Requirement is whenever a variable is created, I need to attach/clone/copy those variables to an object available in a larger scope(say window) . I need this only for debugging purposes. In case such a listener doesnt exist, are there any other ways to do the same? Can something  be done on the js engine level( like v8 or others) to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can always to is add explicit assignments to the globals in your code

```
//original code
var x = 10;
x = 1 + 2;

//Transformed version
var x = (window.x = 10);
x = (window.x = 1 + 1);
```

If you want to avoid editing the source code, one trick you can do is use conditional breakpoints. For each line with an assignment to x, create a conditional breakpoint where the condition first assigns `window.x` and then returns true.